# With Java 8 streams, How to find items with specific conditions within a specific period

Tags: java, java-8

I need help to find out how to find something in java which is currently being done in sql. I need to find specific data in a list within a specific time duration using streams

scenario:
I have a Bet Object with String CustId, Instant timestamp, Double betAmount

I need to find all customers which passed the 100.00 limit per 24 hour period, how would i do it in Java 8?

The method would be

```
public List<String> findLimits(List<Bet> bets){
...
}
```

sample data :

```
note: to be parsed in List<Bet>

A00001    2019-01-15T02:01:10   43.00
A00001    2019-01-15T04:00:00   13.00
A00001    2019-01-15T04:01:15   50.00
B00034    2019-01-15T05:00:00   15.00
A00001    2019-01-15T06:56:20   5.00
B00034    2019-01-15T06:57:00   20.00
C00004    2019-01-15T07:01:00   90.00
C00004    2019-01-15T07:11:00   30.00
B00034    2019-01-17T01:00:00   90.00
```

expected result:

```
["A00001","C00004"] (List<String>)
```

note: the list would contain all bets with diff cust id and chronological timestamps

The sliding 24 hour period and grouping the customers combined is a tricky one that i'm trying to solve.

Comment: Group things by the customer ID; then filter the entry set to only contain values which match your criterion; then discard the values. The "matching your criterion" bit can just be a simple method that uses two pointers to slide over the points, keeping track of the sum of bets between the pointers.

Comment: Would this answer about sliding window stream operations help https://stackoverflow.com/a/34159174/2615510 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map dates with the sum of bet amounts. Then filter them.

```
public List<String> findLimits(List<Bet> bets) {
    return bets.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    b -> b.getCustId() + LocalDate.ofInstant(b.getTimestamp(), ZoneOffset.UTC).toString(),
                    Bet::getAmount,
                    (o1, o2) -> o1 + o2))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 100.0)
            .map(e -> e.getKey().substring(0, e.getKey().length() - LocalDate.EPOCH.toString().length()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can group data by customer ID and then analyze sums in 24h periods. As you mentioned records are sorted by date ascending, so `findLimits` method can look like below:

```
class Bet {
    String ID;
    LocalDateTime dateTime;
    BigDecimal value;
}

public List<String> findLimits(List<Bet> bets) {
    BigDecimal sumLimit = new BigDecimal(100);
    Map<String, List<Bet>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Bet>>();
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Bet bet : bets) {
        if (map.get(bet.ID) == null)
            map.put(bet.ID, new ArrayList<Bet>());
        map.get(bet.ID).add(bet);
    }

    for (String ID : map.keySet()) {
        List<Bet> betListForCustomer = map.get(ID);
        boolean customerExceededLimit = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < betListForCustomer.size(); i++) {
            LocalDateTime endOfPeriod = betListForCustomer.get(i).dateTime.plusDays(1); //calculating end of 24h period current data
            BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0);
            for (int j = i; j < betListForCustomer.size() //move start period to next dateTime
                    && endOfPeriod.isAfter(betListForCustomer.get(j).dateTime); j++) { //analyzing to the last date in 24h period or end data set
                sum = sum.add(betListForCustomer.get(j).value);
            }
            if (sum.compareTo(sumLimit) >= 0) { //sum >= 100
                customerExceededLimit = true;
                break; //there is no need to analyze this customer, limit exceeded
            }
        }
        if (customerExceededLimit) {
            result.add(ID);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```