# Functional unzip implementation for potentially infinite streams

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I've implemented functional `unzip()` operation as follows:

```
public static <T, U, V> Tuple2<Stream<U>, Stream<V>> unzip(
        Stream<T> stream, 
        Function<T, Tuple2<U, V>> unzipper) {

    return stream.map(unzipper)
        .reduce(new Tuple2<>(Stream.<U>empty(), Stream.<V>empty()),
            (unzipped, tuple) -> new Tuple2<>(
                Stream.concat(unzipped.$1(), Stream.of(tuple.$1())),
                Stream.concat(unzipped.$2(), Stream.of(tuple.$2()))),
            (unzipped1, unzipped2) -> new Tuple2<>(
                Stream.concat(unzipped1.$1(), unzipped2.$1()),
                Stream.concat(unzipped1.$2(), unzipped2.$2())));
}
```

This works fine, given input streams don't have a lot of elements. This is because accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can cause `StackOverflowException`. According to the [docs of `Stream.concat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-):

> Implementation Note:
>
> Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation. Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can result in deep call chains, or even `StackOverflowException`.

For few elements, my `unzip` implementation works. Given a class `Person`:

```
class Person {

    public final String name;

    public final int age;

    Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

If I have a stream of people:

```
Stream<Person> people = Stream.of(
    new Person("Joe", 52), 
    new Person("Alan", 34), 
    new Person("Peter", 42));
```

I can use my `unzip()` implementation this way:

```
Tuple2<Stream<String>, Stream<Integer>> result = StreamUtils.unzip(people, 
        person -> new Tuple2<>(person.name, person.age));

List<String> names = result.$1()
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // ["Joe", "Alan", "Peter"]
List<Integer> ages = result.$2()
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // [52, 34, 42]
```

Which is correct.

So my question is: **is there a way for `unzip()` to work with many elements (potentially infinite)?**

*Note:* for completeness, here's my immutable `Tuple2` class:

```
public final class Tuple2<A, B> {

    private final A $1;

    private final B $2;

    public Tuple2(A $1, B $2) {
        this.$1 = $1;
        this.$2 = $2;
    }

    public A $1() {
        return $1;
    }

    public B $2() {
        return $2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860533/copy-a-stream-to-avoid-stream-has-already-been-operated-upon-or-closed-java-8 Somehow to do this effectively, we'd need to clone the given stream in 2 stream and iterate independently on each of them. The only I see how to that (and supporting multithreading) would be to collect all elements in a list beforehand...

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for that link, the point is to do it without collecting, because the input stream could be infinite, and unzipping it should still work.

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474838/can-i-duplicate-a-stream-in-java-8

Comment: No, I would expect this to be impossible.  Java 8 streams are not like the sorts of streams in other languages where this might be possible.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yep, I believe this is not possible, at least the way I'm trying. If I use a collection to keep input stream elements and then create two streams from there, I might run out of memory. If I create new streams via concatenation while reducing the input stream (as In my question), I would get a stack overflow exception. I see no way out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is not only prone to potential `StackOverflowError`s, it is far away from handling potentially infinity streams, even if the risk of a `StackOverflowError` didn’t exist. The point is, you are constructing a stream, but it’s a stream of concatenated single element streams, one for each element of the source stream. In other words, you have a fully materialized data structure upon return of the `unzip` method which will consume even more memory than the result of collecting into an `ArrayList` or a simple `toArray()` operation.

However, when you want to perform `collect` afterwards, the idea of supporting potentially infinite streams is moot anyway, as collecting implies processing of all elements without short-circuiting.

Once you drop the idea of supporting infinite streams and focus on the collect operation, there’s a simpler solution. Taking the code from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35865457/2711488), replacing `Pair` with `Tuple2` and changing the accumulator logic from “conditional” to “both”, we get:

```
public static <T, A1, A2, R1, R2> Collector<T, ?, Tuple2<R1,R2>> both(
    Collector<T, A1, R1> first, Collector<T, A2, R2> second) {

    Supplier<A1> s1=first.supplier();
    Supplier<A2> s2=second.supplier();
    BiConsumer<A1, T> a1=first.accumulator();
    BiConsumer<A2, T> a2=second.accumulator();
    BinaryOperator<A1> c1=first.combiner();
    BinaryOperator<A2> c2=second.combiner();
    Function<A1,R1> f1=first.finisher();
    Function<A2,R2> f2=second.finisher();
    return Collector.of(
        ()->new Tuple2<>(s1.get(), s2.get()),
        (p,t)->{ a1.accept(p.$1(), t); a2.accept(p.$2(), t); },
        (p1,p2)->new Tuple2<>(c1.apply(p1.$1(), p2.$1()), c2.apply(p1.$2(), p2.$2())),
        p -> new Tuple2<>(f1.apply(p.$1()), f2.apply(p.$2())));
}
```

This can be used like

```
Tuple2<List<String>, List<Integer>> namesAndAges=
    Stream.of(new Person("Joe", 52), new Person("Alan", 34), new Person("Peter", 42))
        .collect(both(
            Collectors.mapping(p->p.name, Collectors.toList()),
            Collectors.mapping(p->p.age,  Collectors.toList())));
List<String> names = namesAndAges.$1(); // ["Joe", "Alan", "Peter"]
List<Integer> ages = namesAndAges.$2(); // [52, 34, 42]
```

The statement of the linked answer also holds here. You can do almost everything you can express as a stream operation within a collector.

If you want to be closer to your original code with a function, mapping from the stream element to a `Tuple2`, you can wrap above solution like

```
public static <T, T1, T2, A1, A2, R1, R2> Collector<T, ?, Tuple2<R1,R2>> both(
    Function<? super T, ? extends Tuple2<? extends T1, ? extends T2>> f,
    Collector<T1, A1, R1> first, Collector<T2, A2, R2> second) {

    return Collectors.mapping(f, both(
            Collectors.mapping(Tuple2::$1, first),
            Collectors.mapping(Tuple2::$2, second)));
}
```

and use it like

```
Tuple2<List<String>, List<Integer>> namesAndAges=
    Stream.of(new Person("Joe", 52), new Person("Alan", 34), new Person("Peter", 42))
        .collect(both(
            p -> new Tuple2<>(p.name, p.age), Collectors.toList(), Collectors.toList()));
```

You may recognize the function `p -> new Tuple2<>(p.name, p.age)`, just like the one you passed to your `unzip` method. The above solutions are lazy but require the operations after “unzipping” to be expressed as collectors. If you want `Stream`s instead and accept the non-lazy nature of the solution, much like your original `unzip` operation, but want it to be more efficient than `concat`, you may use:

```
public static <T, U, V> Tuple2<Stream<U>, Stream<V>> unzip(
    Stream<T> stream,  Function<T, Tuple2<U, V>> unzipper) {

    return stream.map(unzipper)
        .collect(Collector.of(()->new Tuple2<>(Stream.<U>builder(), Stream.<V>builder()),
            (unzipped, tuple) -> {
                unzipped.$1().accept(tuple.$1()); unzipped.$2().accept(tuple.$2());
            },
            (unzipped1, unzipped2) -> {
                unzipped2.$1().build().forEachOrdered(unzipped1.$1());
                unzipped2.$2().build().forEachOrdered(unzipped1.$2());
                return unzipped1;
            },
            tuple -> new Tuple2<>(tuple.$1().build(), tuple.$2().build())
        ));
}
```

This can work as a drop in replacement for your `concat` based solution. It will also fully store the stream elements, but it will use a `Stream.Builder` which is optimized for the use case of being incrementally filled and consumed once (in a `Stream` operation). This works even more efficient than collecting into an `ArrayList` (at least with the reference implementation) as it uses a “spined buffer” which doesn’t require copying when increasing the capacity. For streams with a potentially unknown size, this is the most efficient solution (for streams with a known size, `toArray()` will perform even better).

Comment: Thanks @Holger, for such a complete answer. Initially, I wrote unzip with `collect()`, but I switched to `reduce()` because I was getting an `IllegalStateException` (stream already consumed). All your implementations work great, though. You're right in that I didn't want to collect to an `ArrayList`, but instead, I was creating my own linked list by invoking `concat()` repeatedly :) My bad