# Java Stream API - is it possible to create Collector that is collecting result to a new stream?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

So, the question is pretty self-explanatory: is there a way to create a Collector, that is collecting stream that is passed to it into a new stream?

I am aware that it can be done with some tricks like:

`Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), List::stream);`

But this code allocates redundant memory.

Explanation on why do I need this in the first place: sometimes I want to pass something to `Collectors.groupingBy` and then perform a *stream* operation on a downstream, without collecting it additional time.

Is there a simple way to do it (without writing my own class implementing the collector interface)?

EDIT: This question has been marked as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474838/can-i-duplicate-a-stream-in-java-8) question, but that is not what I'm looking for. I do not want to duplicate the original stream, I want to close it and produce a new stream consisting of the same elements in the same order, by the means of Collector and without allocating memory in between.

Comment: Collector, collects the stream into a collection. Before the collection it always is a stream. Why collect it if you still want to use the stream? Maybe I have not undestood something deeper that you meant, however it seems to me that you want to collect your stream and then stream it again.

Comment: Construction I have described in the question is useful when I pass the Collector into another Collector, for example, `Collectors.groupingBy`, and thus, it will operate on another stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collect method will accept a collector.

Parts of the collectors are the following

- Supplier - For a stream, it could be `Stream.empty()` for example
- Accumulator - For streams, we can use `Stream.concat()`
- Combiner - Since this takes a `BinaryOperator` and you'll need to work on the first element because it will be the reference. For lists for example, you get `l1` and `l2` and usually do `l1.addAll(l2)`

So, further than being very complicated, the overhead in terms of memory allocation will be bigger than just collecting everything in a collection first.

Everything is possible, however, you'll probably need to write your own collector that will suite your needs.

You can even rewrite the same exact collector as `groupingBy`, but is it really worth it?